# Fast typing in WPF RichTextBox mixes up events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, richtextbox

I'm trying to implement a simple autocorrect feature in a WPF `RichTextBox`.  In particular, two of the features are 1.) abbreviation expansion (when you type "idk" and a space, the "idk" is replaced by "I don't know") and 2.) adding a period at the end of a line.  I'm implementing this through the `PreviewKeyDown` event, detecting when a word delimiter (for abbreviation expansion) or carriage return (for adding a period) occurs.  It works for the most part, but I see an odd behavior when typing extremely fast.  It seems that the character insertion into the text can occur *after* the `PreviewKeyDown` event for a subsequent key.

For example, supposed you want to enter the abbreviation "idk" followed by a carriage return, so you'll end up with the line "I don't know."  If you type "id", then type "k" and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in quick succession, the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key occurs *before* the "k" is inserted into the text.  So the `PreviewKeyDown` event code doesn't see the complete "idk" abbreviation to be expanded -- it just sees the "id".  And then it puts the period at the end of the "id" (due to the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key).  The "k" is finally inserted into the text after that, so that the result is "id.k"

It's a very peculiar case. If you don't hit the "k" and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys almost simultaneously, it doesn't occur.  I have a demo app where I use a WPF key simulator library to send the characters immediately after each other.  The application is here: https://github.com/garzooma/RichTextBoxDemo.  The key simulator library is here [https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfsendkeys]](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfsendkeys).

I've tried putting flags to delay the processing of the second keystroke, but that just hangs everything up -- the 1st keystroke is never processed.

In my demo app, I try a hack where the code detects when a character hasn't been processed before a subsequent key press happens, by setting a flag in the `PreviewTextInput` event handler and clearing it in the `TextChanged` handler.  When the `PreviewKeyDown` code sees the flag, I set an Action variable that gets processed in the subsequent `TextChanged` event.  This seems to work.  But I'm hoping to find a way to get the problem not to occur.

The basic code is:

```
private void PreviewKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // See if we're at the end of a word
  if (delimiterKeys.Contains(e.Key))
  {
    string word = GetPrecedingText();
    // Is the word an abbreviation?
    if (abbreviations.ContainsKey(word.ToUpper()))
    {
      TextPointer pointer = textbox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(-word.Length);
      if (pointer.LogicalDirection == LogicalDirection.Backward)  // change direction, if needed
      {
        pointer = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        textbox1.CaretPosition = pointer;
      }
      // replace abbreviation w/expansion
      pointer.DeleteTextInRun(word.Length);
      pointer.InsertTextInRun(abbreviations[word.ToUpper()]);
    }
    // Are we at the end of a line, and don't have a period?
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !word.EndsWith("."))
    {
      TextPointer pointer = textbox1.CaretPosition;
      if (pointer.LogicalDirection == LogicalDirection.Backward)  // change direction, if needed
      {
        pointer = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        textbox1.CaretPosition = pointer;
      }
      pointer.InsertTextInRun(".");
    }
}
```